# Is there a way to not return a response from a Django view?

Tags: python, ajax, django

Say I want to do a ajax get request that goes to a Django view.  Instead of returning a response to the client, could I store the request in a dictionary or list and forget about it for a while leaving the ajax/client waiting for a response?  Then say after something happens on the server I use another view or function to retrieve the request and create a response from it and send it to the client.

This is kind of like a ajax push approach?

Is this possible to be done in Django and if so how efficient is it?

Answer (score 2):

Django uses WSGI which is designed for synchronous processing, so doing what you want is not easy. That said there is one guy who seems to have done [implementation for asynchronous responses](http://blogger.popcnt.org/2007/12/asynchronous-django-responses-comet-yes.html). That's probably not the most efficient or reliable, but at least it's possible.

Comment: i wasn't really looking for an asynchronous way of doing this, in fact, i want the view function to finish/return just not return a response for django to return so on the client side the ajax is still waiting for a response.